# pandas transform one row into multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below.

My dataframe as below.

```
ID      list
1       a, b, c
2       a, s
3       NA
5       f, j, l
```

I need to break each items in the list column(String) into independent row as below:

```
ID      item
1       a
1       b
1       c
2       a
2       s
3       NA
5       f
5       j
5       l
```

Thanks.

Comment: use pandas explode with pandas str split. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html the split option converts your list column into a list, and the explode puts each item into it's own row

Comment: Thanks. list column is a string type and not list type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.split` to separate your items then `explode`:

```
print (df.assign(list=df["list"].str.split(", ")).explode("list"))

   ID list
0   1    a
0   1    b
0   1    c
1   2    a
1   2    s
2   3  NaN
3   5    f
3   5    j
3   5    l
```

Answer (score 0):

A beginners approach : Just another way of doing the same thing using `pd.DataFrame.stack`

```
df['list'] = df['list'].map(lambda x : str(x).split(','))
dfOut = pd.DataFrame(df['list'].values.tolist())
dfOut.index = df['ID']
dfOut = dfOut.stack().reset_index()
del dfOut['level_1']
dfOut.rename(columns = {0 : 'list'}, inplace = True)
```

Output:

```
   ID list
0   1    a
1   1    b
2   1    c
3   2    a
4   2    s
5   3  nan
6   5    f
7   5    j
8   5    l
```